# Set "" to radcontrols in javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik

I am using Telerik control RadNumericTextBox and I want to set empty string "" to it in javascript function.

How to do this for the below code

```
$find('<%= FindControl("txtAmount").ClientID %>').value = "";
```

Need  correction in the above code.

Comment: Is my question not clear or looking as silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$find('<%= FindControl("txtAmount").ClientID %>').set_value("");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('txtAmount').value = '';
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#txtAmount').val('');
```

Try this